# How to see that a one-object pre-additive category is a ring?

Tags: category-theory

There are two previous questions ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345004/is-it-possible-to-define-a-ring-as-a-category),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235731/can-rings-be-represented-in-category-theory?rq=1)) that ask whether it's possible to define a ring as a specific type of category. In both cases, the accepted answer is that a ring is a one-object [preadditive category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadditive_category) (aka linear category), which is "a category enriched over the monoidal category of Abelian groups." I more or less understand what this means, but it's not at all clear to me how to see this as a ring.

The issue is that an Abelian group has only one binary operation. From the Wikipedia article I gather that I should see this as multiplication. But to be a ring there should also be a notion of addition, and I can't see where this comes from.

Consequently I am looking for a gentler explanation of how a one-element preadditive category can be seen as a ring. Specifically, how are addition and multiplication are defined in terms of a preadditive category, and how can I see that they obey the ring axioms?

<sub>**Side note:** my motivation is to think about mappings from categories to numbers. For example, in probability theory a sigma algebra is a partial order, and hence a category, and a measure is a function from the elements of a sigma algebra to the reals in $[0,1]$. It seems like it would be productive to think of this as a functor from the sigma algebra to some appropriately defined category of real numbers. For this to be useful it seems that we would need a way of referring to addition and multiplication of reals, which is why I'm asking this question. However, it's entirely possible that I should be asking a different question instead, or that there is a paper that already spells all this out. If that's the case I'd really appreciate comments.</sub>

Comment: The Abelian group structure gives the additive structure (seeing as it's commutative). The other obvious binary operation in a preadditive category is composition which gives the multiplicative structure.

Comment: @DerekElkins thanks, I was just figuring that out as you posted it. (Feel free to write it as an answer if you care about points, otherwise I'll write a self answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-answer: to be a ring we need two binary operations. The fact that the hom-set is an Abelian group provides one of these, which is to be interpreted as addition (and not multiplication as I wrongly wrote in the question). The other is given by composition of morphisms, which is interpreted as multiplications. A preadditive category is defined such that multiplication distributes over addition, which is why the ring axioms are obeyed. (At the time of writing, the Wikipedia article doesn't make that last point clear; I'll edit it shortly.)